# What causes a glottal stop after some silence before a vowel?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, pronunciation, glottal-stop

I recently asked a question [Do we pronounce the vowel at the beginning of the word with a preceding glottal stop?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/547942/do-we-pronounce-the-vowel-at-the-beginning-of-the-word-with-a-preceding-glottal) on the English site and received a very good answer.

According to the answer on that question, *English speakers usually pronounce words beginning with a vowel, with a glottal stop when following a pause.* That answer explained also that *[I]n Hawaiian, the distinction is phonemic i.e. /ahi/ and /ʔahi/ have different meanings*. But in English, it is *phonetic* (allophonic).

I wonder what causes us to have a glottal stop before a vowel after some silence. What happens to our vocal cords when we start from silence? I tried to pronounce a "pure vowel" at the beginning without trying to pronounce a glottal stop but I can't do that.

What causes our vocal cords to produce a glottal stop before a vowel after some silence? Is there a phonetic (or phonological?) explanation for this?

Comment: Your vocal cords usually close when they’re not in use (to close off access to your windpipe and prevent things getting into your throat). Pronouncing a vowel without a glottal stop requires first opening the cords, then starting the vowel; with a glottal stop, you basically open the cords by pushing the air needed to produce the vowel at them and relaxing. The former requires more accurate timing, so if there’s no phonemic opposition, it’s often easier for speakers to do the latter.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet please don't use comments section for answering the question. Write a full-featured answer instead so it can be upvoted and accepted by the OP.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet prevents things like... air? the glottis does close off maybe not the whole windpipe, a glottal stop if I try to force it does though

Comment: it does prevent accidental sounds from getting out anyway

Comment: Vowels can be more clearly articulated if there's some amount of sub-glottal pressure. If a vowel is utterance-initial then a way to get some sub-glottal pressure is with a glottal stop.

Comment: imagine a glottal-less onset like in *soup* modulo the initial /s/. Incidently, *oops*, *whoops* or German *Hups*, *Ups* are synonymous.

Comment: I just want to remark that a glottal stop before an isolated vowel is far from being universal. While German has it (named *harter Vokaleinsatz* in German terminology) French doesn't (named *weicher Vokaleinsatz* in German terminology).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet *Your vocal cords usually close when they're not in use*. Ha ha! That's true if you're dead, of course, but then you don't use them! They're normally open, because you need to breathe! It's normally a requirement that your windpipe be open!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Yeah, I did wonder how to best phrase that. I meant while you’re in a speaking situation, but not actively producing sound. Of course, in general, they remain open most of the time for breathing, but I at least automatically close them when I stop speaking until the next time I breathe in or out (or start speaking again). But I freely admit that ‘to prevent things getting into your throat’ is possibly just post-rationalisation on my part – I’d never thought about why I do it before, it just seemed like a logical physiology-based incentive…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I don't think you probably do close them when you stop speaking though. If you did, you'd have a glottal stop at the end of any utterance-final vowel. For example if you made an interjection like *yeah*, for example. I don't know if you do do that, but it doesn't seem very commonplace to me ... ;)

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Not an immediate closure (unless the word actually ends in a glottal stop, of course), but they close perhaps something like half a second or so after the voicing stops. I can keep them open, but it feels unnatural, like I’m trying to say ‘yeah’ and then trail straight off into an audible exhale, so I’m pretty sure I do do it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In a comment, Janus Bahs Jacquet wrote:

> Your vocal cords usually close when they’re not in use (to close off access to your windpipe and prevent things getting into your throat). Pronouncing a vowel without a glottal stop requires first opening the cords, then starting the vowel; with a glottal stop, you basically open the cords by pushing the air needed to produce the vowel at them and relaxing. The former requires more accurate timing, so if there’s no phonemic opposition, it’s often easier for speakers to do the latter.